# Stuck with Visual Studio and local MySql Database

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I'm having a bit troubles with getting my data into my website.
I am working with this tutorial.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2/displaying-data

I know, it is outdated so I'm trying to do the same thing in visual studio.
I downloaded MySQL and connected it successfully to visual studio.

Now I ran into the problem that in the tutorial they use the command

Database.Open

But this is not working for me. I just have no idea how I can access the data in my database to be displayed on the website.

Any tips on this? Thank you

Comment: There is an MySQL ODBC connection https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/5.3.html

Comment: I just skimmed your link and it looks like that was designed for "WebMatrix creates a SQL Server CE database"; that is not MySQL. You'll want to use either an ODBC connector as @JacquesAmar pointed out; or the MySQL .net connector.

Comment: I have the MySQL connector installed, and have the database already connected to my visual studio. My problem now is, how to work with the database or how to display the data in my web project.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with classes?
You could use something like:

```
OleDbConnection oleConn = new OleDbConnection();
public DataTable GetQueryString(string strQuery)
    {
        OleDbDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        DataTable dttData = new DataTable();

        using (oleConn = new OleDbConnection("Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;"))
        {
            sqlAdapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(strQuery, oleConn);
            sqlAdapter.Fill(dttData);
            oleConn.Close();
            oleConn.Dispose();
        }
        return dttData;
    }
```

And the use will be something like

```
YourClass clsConn = new YourClass();
DataTable dttData = clsConn.GetQueryString("select * from myTable");
```